Problem matching new terminal window ID with xdotool in Bash
I have a script that kicks off a new terminal window that I want to move to a specific position on the left terminal using xdotool.
After kicking off the terminal I run
xdotool search --class gnome-term

and I use the returned Window ID in the xdotool windowsize and windowmove commands to size and position the new terminal window.
xdotool windowsize $WIN_ID 1978 407
xdotool windowmove &WIN_ID -26 702

Since I have multiple terminals running I need to identify which WIN_ID is associated with the last terminal window just created.
In the script I execute the below command before launching the new terminal to get a list of existing WIN_IDs.
for i in `xdotool search --class gnome-term`; do id_list="$id_list $i"; done

Sample content of $id_list:
65011713 65011722 65103242 65019818 65029314 65027106

After launcing the new terminal, to identify the new WIN_ID, I run this test.
for WID in `xdotool search --class gnome-term`; do if [[ ! $WID =~  $id_list ]]; then echo "New Window ID = $WID"; fi; done

When I run this command, instead of getting just one (the new) Window ID, I get all the Window IDs associated with the gnome-terminal class. Why is the below command not returning only the WID that isn't in id_list?
if [[ ! $WID =~  $id_list ]]; then ...

Script:
...
...
# Generate a list of Window IDs for existing gnome-terminal windows
for i in `xdotool search --class gnome-term`; do id_list="$id_list $i"; done

# Kick off a new terminal window
gnome-terminal

# Get the Window ID of the new terminal window
New_WID=`for WID in `xdotool search --class gnome-term`; do if [[ ! $WID =~  $id_list ]]; then echo $WID"; fi; done`
...
...

Thanks for time and feedback!
Tex

because it's [[ string =~ regex ]], not the other way around. Swap $WID and $id_list.

duh! Thank you very much!

note that a string comparison like that can hit on substrings too, i.e. the list 1234 5678 would seem to also contain e.g. 234. If that matters, you might try to add spaces, something like list="1234 5678" id=234; [[ " $list " =~ " $id " ]]

Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process. Also, posting script fragments doesn't give us context - please post the whole script, unless it's too big (and if it's too big, is bash the right choice, is your design questionable?)

@waltinator Thanks for the shellcheck.net pointer!

another approach: store current pids as indices in an array (eg, pidlist[123]=1; pidlist[456]=1); the comparison then becomes [[ -z "${pidlist[WID]}" ]] && New_WID="$WID"

or perhaps an associative array instead, not that it matters in Bash or ksh where regular arrays are sparse, but e.g. zsh arrays autogenerate all intervening elements...

@markp-fuso Thanks for suggestion and sample code.

Your for i in xdotool search --class gnome-term; do id_list="$id_list $i"; done is more straightforwardly written as id_list=$(xdotool search --class gnome-term)

If you want to find the window ids that appear since last time you ran xdotool search --class gnome-term, basically that's doing a list subtraction.
Can be done with for instance:
#! /bin/zsh -
die() { print -ru2 -C1 -- "$@"; exit 1; }
before=( $(xdotool search --class gnome-term) )
gnome-terminal
after=( $(xdotool search --class gnome-term) )
new_wid=( ${after:|before} )
(( $#new_wid == 1 )) || die "$#new_wid new window${new_wid[2]+s} found"
xdotool windowsize $new_wid 1000 500 $new_wid 12582932 -26 702

If you had to use bash which doesn't have a list subtraction operator, you could use comm to do it:
#! /bin/bash -
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
die() { println>&2 "$@"; exit 1; }
before=( $(xdotool search --class gnome-term | sort) )
gnome-terminal
after=( $(xdotool search --class gnome-term | sort) )
new_wid=( $(comm -13 <(println "${before[@]}") <(println "${after[@]}")) )
(( ${#new_wid[@]} == 1 )) ||
  die "${#new_wid[@]} new window${new_wid[1]+s} found"
xdotool windowsize "$new_wid" 1978 407 "$new_wid" 12582932 -26 702


Thank you for stretching my knowledge! Very cool!
